# Custom Webpart to set the filters and display SharePoint list items?

Tags: web-part, application-pages, datatable

I have a requirement where list items are stored in multiple folders. Now users should be able to apply the filters as they would do if they do not have folders.

It looks like I have a build a custom webpart or application page that would allow them to set the filter and display the items on a button click.

How would I approach this problem? Probably I should have some controls like Textbox and Dropdown controls, use the CAML query to get the result and display it on the Datatable?

Any thoughts?

Comment: It's not hard to set up a search page with filters (refiners.) It gives you the flexibility to choose multi-select or single select dropdowns, and SharePoint will handle the results

Comment: Any links or reference? Basically users do not want to search instead they should be able to apply filter as they would do normally on a List.

Comment: Right - you don't need the search inbox, it will show all items as default. Only concern I may have is what's your permission level ?

Comment: I have use both CSOM+CAML query and search results web part to achieve this kind of requirement, but search was much easier. The only downside is depending on the version, SharePoint can take up to 15 mins to roll up data.